$f\left(x+1,y+1\right)=\frac{f\left(x+1,y\right)+f\left(x,y+1\right)}{2}+1$
The problem
$\forall x,y \in \mathbb{W}  \\ f(x,0)=f(0,y)= 0 \\ f(1,1)=1 \\ \forall x,y \in \mathbb{N} \\
f\left(x+1,y+1\right)=\frac{f\left(x+1,y\right)+f\left(x,y+1\right)}{2}+1$
When I tried easier cases,
I know that for $f_0\left(x+1,y+1\right)=f_0\left(x+1,y\right)+f_0\left(x,y+1\right)$ that's kind of pascal's triangle by pascal identity, so $f_0\left(x,y\right)=\binom{x+y}{y}=\binom{x+y}{x}=\frac{(x+y)!}{x!y!}$ the table of first values
For $f_1\left(x+1,y+1\right)=\frac{f_1\left(x+1,y\right)+f_1\left(x,y+1\right)}{2}$ the solution is $f_1(x,y)=\frac{(x+y)!}{x!y!2^{x+y}}$ the first values
and $f(x,y)=\sum_{m=0}^{y-1}\sum_{n=0}^{x-1}\frac{\left(m+n\right)!}{m!n!2^{n+m}}$ the finale table,the graph of f(x,y)
The graphes of the first values of y is here and from some reason they are the interpolation of some dots on the line $y=2x$
How I can simpledied the sum or the interpolation? there isother way to solve?

To clarify, you have the solution (the double sum), you are just trying to find a way to simplify it?

It's possible to write the inner sum as a hypergeometric function, but I would not consider that simpler. I doubt there is a simpler form then the double sum.

@Sil you are right
